# How to open a url in sencha touch panel?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I developed a twitter mobile web app using Sench Touch 2. In my iPhone, I open it and add it to homescreen. When I click a link from the app, it will jump out of the app and open the url using Safari. When I return to my app, it needs to reload itself again. So, I wanna know is there a way to open a link in my own app using another panel view?

Comment: you could use iframe inside panel and on click of link load frame with new url.

Comment: @SachinG, I found the same solution in sencha touch forum, but it is said that script or scroller may not well in iframe

Answer (score 0):

If you build your app with phonegap, there is an entry in 'config.xml':

```
<!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, -->
<!-- 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
<preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />
```

Comment: I am not using phonegap, this is a pure web app, but I put the icon in the desktop using the iOS Safari feature 'add to home screen', so it behaviors like a standalone app.